# Getting error: Username and Password mismatch, when tried to test login rest api?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

Following  I am tried to write test cases for login api, when I write test out-side any class then it does not gives any error, But when I created class     `class TestCase(TestCase):` and define method `def test_login(self):`. It gives password miss-match, but outside same code running successfully.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
import json

#Creating test out side class


credential=dict()
c =Client()
credential["username"]="john"
credential["password"]="xxx"
response =c.put('/api/login', data=json.dumps(credential)) 

print("content")
print(response.content)

"""
{"message": "", "result": {"username": "john", "session_key": "xyz"}, "error": 0}
"""


print("session_key")
content = json.loads(response.content)
key = content['result']['session_key']
print key


#Creating test inside class


class TestCase(TestCase):
   def test_login(self):
      User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")
      credential=dict()
      c =Client()
      credential["username"]="john"
      credential["password"]="xxx"
      response =c.put('/api/login', data=json.dumps(credential))
      content=json.loads(response.content)
      print 'content'
      print content


     {u'message': u'Username and Password mismatch', u'result': {}, u'error': 1}
```

Here we can see message are different format for **successful**
`{"message": "", "result": {"username": "john", "session_key": "xyz"}, "error": 0}`

For **Unsuccessful**
`{u'message': u'Username and Password mismatch', u'result': {}, u'error': 1}`. There is `u` before every variable. I think problem is here....

Comment: The u is there because it is a unicode string...

Comment: @petkostas Then why it is not in the first case, Why I am getting password mismatch when I wrote test inside class TestCase, but not giving error when I wrote samething outsude class. Please help me on thi

Answer (score 0):

[Tests use a separate database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) that is created for that test run, you need to create a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures) to populate the database with that user or just add the code to create one before the `login` call, something like:

```
User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")
```

Comment: Where should I write `User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")` ?

Comment: anywhere in your test before the `login` call, I suggest right at the top

Comment: Please see the updated question, I put like above `User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")` in the code..

Comment: Getting error `NameError: global name 'User' is not defined`

Comment: you need to import the django `User` model, add `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` right at the top of the file

Comment: Still getting username and password missmatch,

Comment: how are you running your tests? why do you have `{u'message': u'Username and Password mismatch', u'result': {}, u'error': 1}` right at the end of the test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90031/discussion-between-geeks-and-yeray-diaz-diaz).